# Set MySQL innodb buffer pool size on IIS7

Tags: mysql, innodb, buffer

I am using VPS, Windows 2008 r2, IIS7, MYSQL 5.1.73,
Hardward Config: Ram 2GB , Hardisk 40GB

On this VPS only 1 .NET application is running. Application is currently using by only 5 users.
I found MySQL server INNODB BUFFER USAGE is 100%

I found some suggestions like change buffer size in my.cnf or my.ini file, but I didn't find any file on VPS. I have tried below command as well

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 33554432
```

but its giving me an error as

> Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is a read only variable

Can any one please suggest me a solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) requires restarting MySQL. Why ?

Take a look at Percona's Vadim Tkachenko's Pictorial Representation of InnoDB

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

In the upper left corner, you see the InnoDB Buffer Pool. It has Data and Index Pages for InnoDB Tables and a giant scratch pad for migrating secondary index changes from the Buffer Pool to the Insert Buffer. All those things would have to be written to disk and all transactions completed. Since all that must happen, it was best to leave [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) as a static variable.

What you need to do is add that option to my.ini

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M
```

and restart mysql.